# Laravel email notification upon all exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I am developing a project and i would like to have a notification system especially for the "first days of live" - to receive an email everytime an exception is thrown .

I've read that [article](https://laravel-news.com/email-on-error-exceptions) and implemented what it says. My problem is that the function `report()` in  `App\Exception\Handler.php` doesn't trigger if an exception is thrown in one of my Controllers.

**My problem :**
I have an AdminController and a function which inserts some data in Database. The queries are inside a try/catch :

```
try {
    // commands
} catch (\Exception $e){
    Log::channel('admin_submissions')->info("Could not save submission. " . $e->getMessage());
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Could not save submission. Try again!']);
}
```

For testing purposes i've inserted inside the `try{}` an error to be thrown like :

```
try {

    $error = \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
                'field_name_1' => ['Validation Message #1'],
                'field_name_2' => ['Validation Message #2'],
            ]);
    throw $error;

    // commands
```

But the `dd("trigger")` function (look below) is not triggered.

**How could i make it so on every exception (everywhere) an email will be sent?**

> App\Exceptions\Handler.php

I have modified the report function just to check if the exception actually goes through that function :

```
 public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        dd("trigger");

        if ($this->shouldReport($exception)) {
            app('sneaker')->captureException($exception);
        }

        parent::report($exception);
    }
```

Comment: Your intention is to receive a 'log' of errors on your email. My recommendation is to use an error handling service, which will take as little as one hour to integrate in your application. See: https://sentry.io/

Sentry will notify you by email of each error and provide an interface to browse through all the errors in your application.

Comment: remove try catch from  your controller code  and check it is goint to report function

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta This will probably work but i can't do this because i use a DB transaction and on error i must use `DB::rollback()` - plus i log different kind of cases and i want to keep that file logging

Comment: if you throw an Exception inside a `try{}`, that exception will be catch-ed, thus not being handled by the Exceptions Handler.

Answer (score 1):

You must firstly know which kind of exception your application thrown, may be the Exception that is thrown are in the `$dontReport` if so, you must firstly remove all exception from that table on you will get report for that Exception

Comment: `$dontReport` is an empty array so i suppose it should catch any exception right?

Comment: Yes! remove the try catch which you have put in your `AdminController`. because of that `try/catch` block the exception emit will not be handle by the `App\Exceptions\Handler` but by your `catch` block

Comment: If i remove the `try/catch` in `AdminController.php` how can i controll my `DB::beginTransaction()` in case of `catch` which will be caused in `AdminController.php`?

Comment: I think you want to say in case of exception which are thrown in your ~AdminController`. What do you do with your database after you have call `DB::beginTransaction()`? You can perform any action in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` in the `report`, you can perform some query to your database and so on